# Bootstrap 3 min-width of row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have such code:

```
<section class="main row">
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10">
    </div>
</div>
```

But on my notebook col-lg-2 is too small for my needs (while on fullhd desktop it it awesome) so i decided to `min-width:250px` it. But when width of `col-lg-2` is `250px` and i keep resizing browser, my `col-lg-10` jumps to the bottom of `col-lg-2`.

How to prevent it?

Comment: Have any idea abt notebook `screen size`?

Comment: I think you should have post also the html within the `<div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10"></div>`, because bootstrap is a mobile first.

Answer (score 0):

Set fixed width in Bootstrap is not good practice. try use instead of `lg-2` `lg-3`

Or you may use next trick

```
<section class="main row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-10">
          //or any another lg value
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-9">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `lg-3` becomes too huge on fullhd desktop(

Comment: @wingsofovnia Then go to bootstrap media files and change lg size there or setup it on the page http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to specify a custom width here. Just change `md` values

```
<section class="main row">
   <div class="col-md-4 col-lg-2">
   </div>
   <div class="col-md-8 col-lg-10">
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: notebook's resolution is 1366x768 and it is non-`md` col. so this is useless

Comment: Theres no useless code if there is a point I assure you that @wingsofovnia.